# Is it possible to automatically remove the same object from every page in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, indesign-scripting

I have a pre-made document and I want to remove a line (same length, same stroke, same color) from every page. Is there a quick way to do this aside from deleting manually?

Comment: Is it correct to think its not on your master page?

Comment: Like @Ryan almost said, if the object exists in a master page, then it is easy to remove from any number of pages. Another method would be to make alayer for this specific object and then remove the layer and the object is removed from every page.

Comment: this would be relatively easy to script. But i dont see this as something that happens often.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Find / Change` to search for objects and automatically change their attributes, but I don't know of a way to delete the objects in the same step.

Perhaps you could change the strokes to have both a Fill and Stroke color of None, thus making them disappear. Something like that.

**Edit:** since this was helpful, I added a screen shot.

[image]

You can either click Find and go through each object individually, or click Change All and the attributes of all objects of the defined type will be changed.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found that the stroke had an almost unique characteristic - .5pt stroke.  Only a few other objects shared the same stroke width, so I used find/change to change all .5pt to 20pt and changed the (now) obvious exceptions. Afterwards, I just did a search and find next/delete (button) manually and mindlessly. Thanks for the help.